# Unable to install npm package hosted on a private registry with jspm

Tags: jspm

I am trying to get jspm working with a private npm registry (which mirrors the public registry).

I used the endpoint config tool to configure jspm from .npmrc appears to work successfully

```
GAVINJ:jspm-test gavinj$ jspm endpoint config npm
npmrc found, would you like to use these settings? [yes]:
npm registry [http://registry.npm.ourcompanyname.net/]:
Would you like to test these credentials? [yes]:
ok   npm authentication is working successfully.
ok   Endpoint npm configured successfully.
```

Installing our package 'michelangelo' (which is not in the public npm registry) works just fine

```
GAVINJ:jspm-test gavinj$ npm install michelangelo
highstock-release@2.0.4 node_modules/highstock-release
jquery@2.1.3 node_modules/jquery
d3@3.5.5 node_modules/d3
lodash@3.3.1 node_modules/lodash
michelangelo@2.0.1641 node_modules/michelangelo
```

Attempting to install the same npm package via jspm does not work.

```
GAVINJ:jspm-test gavinj$ jspm install michelangelo=npm:michelangelo
     Looking up npm:michelangelo

err  Repo michelangelo not found!

warn Installation changes not saved.
```

Attempting to install lodash via jspm works perfectly

```
GAVINJ:jspm-test gavinj$ jspm install lodash=npm:lodash
     Looking up npm:lodash
     Updating registry cache...
     Looking up github:jspm/nodelibs-process
     Looking up npm:process
ok   Up to date - lodash as npm:lodash@^3.3.1 (3.3.1)
ok   Install tree has no forks.

ok   Install complete.
```

Here's what my jspm config file looks like

```
{
  "registry": "jspm",
  "endpoints": {
    "github": {
      "timeouts": {
        "lookups": 60
      },
      "handler": "jspm-github",
      "remote": "https://github.jspm.io"
    },
    "npm": {
      "timeouts": {
        "lookups": 60
      },
      "registry": "http://registry.npm.ourcompanyname.net/",
      "remote": "https://npm.jspm.io",
      "auth": "PRIVATE_HERE_BUT_SAME_AS_NPMRC_FILE",
      "handler": "jspm-npm"
    },
    "jspm": {
      "timeouts": {
        "lookups": 60
      },
      "handler": "jspm-registry",
      "remote": "https://registry.jspm.io"
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea why I am unable to install the npm pacakge via jspm?  Or, any advice on how I could track down the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the registry url cannot end with a `/`.

Once I removed the trailing slash it worked like a charm.